# Pandas read_csv/to_csv producing inconsistent results

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am working with a large mixed-type pandas DataFrame, and after writing and then re-reading the file using `pandas.DataFrame.read_csv`, there are a significant number of observations that do not match the raw value from the text file (or the original DataFrame). If I open the text file in a text editor and locate a specific value, it will not match after the read.

Example psuedo-code would look something like this

```
# Hard code value found in text file, no additional digits
val = -2.631
# Re-read DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
print df.Var1.iloc[10]
... -2.6310000000000002
print df.Var1.iloc[10] == val
... False
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way python stores floats. There is some loss of precision when the string that you input is converted to a number in memory. You can use the decimal module to accurately convert strings to floats.

```
>>> val = -2.631
>>> val
-2.6309999999999998
>>> import decimal
>>> val = decimal.Decimal('-2.631')
>>> val
Decimal('-2.631')
>>> print val
-2.631
```

I suspect Pandas has some built-in way to handle floats, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same issue. When I called `to_csv()`, it did not match with `read_csv()`.

**I found out that it is because of `pandas.fillna()` function.**

We cannot literally fill null values with "NA" (Perhaps because the letters are reserved)

I checked the way I filled null values

```
  df.fillna("NA")
```

**Changing the String to be passed solved the issue.**

```
  df.fillna("Na")
```

Or you can use other meaningful String

```
  df.fillna("None")
```